# is it possible to make a gird parent container adjust it's height to keep containing the child after the child's position changes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, layout

Is it possible to make the gird parent container adjust it's height to keep containing the child after the child's position changes in CSS ? in this example i have a container(grid) containing 3 child divs (the yellow ones), i want to change the position of one them, but i see that it gets out of it's parent container and hides other elements in the layout, i want to make the parent container adjust(height/width) so it keeps it inside.

```
 <div class="parent Box">
        <div class="ONE"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda, quo.</p></div>
        <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolo sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, non!</p></div>
        <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, enim.</p></div>
    </div>
```

```
.parentBox{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

    .parentBox > div{ 
  border: 3px solid black ;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 162);
}

.ONE{
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

[image: the example]

Comment: Not with position:relative and top, no. Use margin-top instead.

Comment: thanks, but margin changes the height of the div, it doesn't move it around

Answer (score 0):

I could do it by just using the padding-bottom.